# React Router after reload always redirected to dashboard

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have one problem with react routers. 
It's my App class. I check my token, if it valid i do redirect to dashboard page.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.checkAuth = this.checkAuth.bind(this);
}

checkAuth(){
    if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)){
        getCurrentAccount().then(response => {
            this.props.onLoadCurrentAccount({ account: response, isAuthenticated: true });
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAuth();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
                <PrivateRoute authenticated={this.props.account.isAuthenticated} path='/' component={CoreLayout} />
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Here i have different routes to other components if you authorized.
Always when i try to reload page i go to '/' page. For example: i stay on '/contacts' but when i reload page i go to '/'. How can i fix it?

```
class CoreLayout extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Menu/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
                <Route path='/contacts' component={Contacts}/>
                <Route path='/assignment' component={Assignment}/>
                <Route path='/tasks' component={Tasks}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: You are explicitly forcing the `App` component to redirect to `/` if it is loaded with `this.props.history.push('/')`. What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 3):

Due to your `componentDidMount()` Method;

In `componentDidMount()` method you are calling `checkAuth()` method in which you are using

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

so try to change  `checkAuth()`  method as per your requirement.

Comment: To add to this, you can call `push()` from within the `react-router` to redirect without reloading.

Comment: But how i do redirect to private page without push? Sorry for stupid questions, i'm newbie in reactjs.

Comment: You can make use of Redirect, Link tag from react-router

Answer (score 0):

You need to add check before pushing yourself to the homepage. If the user is not Authenticated, redirect it to the home page

```
checkAuth(){
    if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)){
        getCurrentAccount().then(response => {
            this.props.onLoadCurrentAccount({ account: response, isAuthenticated: true });
            if (IS_NOT_AUTHENTICATED) { // Change your condition for if user is not authenticated
             this.props.history.push('/');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillMount() {
sessionStorage.reload = true;
}
render() {
if(sessionStorage.reload && history.location.pathname!=='/') {
  console.log(this.props);
  sessionStorage.reload = "";
  history.push('/login');
} 
return (
  <Router history={ history }>
  <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <>
      <Route path="/" exact strict component={ Loginpage } />
      <Route path="/mapview" exact component={ GoogleMap } />
      <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={ Dashboard } />
      <Route path="/tripList" exact component={ TripList } />
      <Route path="/createTrips" exact component={ CreateTrips } />
      <Route path="/trace" exact component={ trace } />
      <Route path="/vehicleinfo" component={ vehicleinfo } />
      <Route path="/MyPeople" component={ MyPeople } />
      <Route path="/AddForm" component={ MyPeople } />
      <Route path="/ListView" component={ ListView } />
      <Route path="/fleetAlerts" component={FleetAlerts} />

      <Route path="/login" exact component={ Loginpage } />
      </> 
    </Switch>
  </div>
  </Router>
);
}
```

Once I will reload the application, it will execute the component will unmount function to set the session storage and check the render function inside session is available or not if available to apply the history.push('\') or whatever you want

Comment: Once i will reload the application, it will execute the componentwillunmount function to set the session storage and check the render function inside session is availabe or not if available to apply the history.push('\') or whatever you want